# Is it possible to create multiple screens, with only one Activity in an Android application?

Tags: android, blackberry, dynamic, stack, screen

Normally I would use a separate activity for each "screen" I wish to display, using different XML files.

However I'm working with Dynamically loading jar files into an android application, so therefore at runtime, I am not aware of how many activities there will be, or how many screens there will be.

At the moment, using java reflection, I am able to return a list of strings from the dynamically loaded java file, and draw each list item, as a separate button onto the screen. If one of these buttons is clicked, i want to be able to load a different "screen" on the stack. So when I press back from this new screen, it goes to the previous screen that called it.

Is it possible to do this without creating a new activity and passing a new intent to it and of course making relevant changes to the android manifest file?

To use blackberry functionality as an example - Is there an equivalent in android to blackberry's push and pop screens? Where the screen ur pushing/popping, would simply extent MainScreen?

If anyone has questions, or If I've been vague, please comment and I will try my best to explain myself, any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: yes, it's possible you need to use fragments, https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: "I'm working with Dynamically loading jar files into an android application" -- why?

Comment: Well I have multiple separate modules that I want to load dynamically into my "Main Android Application". Each module is only accessible based on a set of permissions. If the user logging in has the required permissions to view modules 1,2,3 out of 1,2,3,4,5 - then only module 1,2,3 will be dynamically loaded.

The reason why I want to do this, is to only load modules which are required and not do more work. The main android application would simply be responsible for containing these modules. I hope the dynamically loaded jar that contains a module - can be an activity.

Comment: As long as I specify the Activity name in the Main Android Applications manifest file - I should be able to dynamically load a jar contained an Android Activity java file with the same name. Theoretically, I think this would work, however I've been having trouble with the .dex files and the dalvik cache - Which is a whole other issue.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all the answers - I've begun focusing my attention on web services at the moment. I will choose an answer as soon as I try every suggestion out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you should use Fragment. I assume that you have some piece of code where you iterate over the strings:

```
for(String def : definitions) {
   Fragment f = new CustomFragment();
   Bundle b = new Bundle();
   b.putString("STRING_DEF",def);
   f.setArguments(b);
   fragments.add(f);
}
```

in above piece of code a collection of `Framents` is just created. Let's look at the `CustomFragment` implementation:

```
CustomFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String def = getArguments.getString("STRING_DEF");
        //write code to create view
        return view;
    }
}
```

Now in your `ListActivity` you have to implement on click listener more or less like this like this

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    FragmentManager fragMgr = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction t = fragMgr.beginTransaction();
    t.replace(R.id.id_of_view_place_holder_for_fragment, 
        fragments.get(position),"FRAGMENT_TAG");
    t.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Android equivalent to BB's push/pop screen is `startActivity()`/`finish()`. However, you can manage your own views in a single activity by either using a container view (such as `ViewSwitcher`, as @hasanghaforian suggests) or by simply calling `setContentView()` with a new view hierarchy whenever you want to change the screen. Be aware that when you call `setContentView`, any view references that you obtained by calling `findViewById` will be stale.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ViewSwitcher`. ViewSwitcher is a ViewAnimator that **switches between two views**, and has a factory from which these views are created. You can either use the factory to create the views, or add them yourself. A ViewSwitcher can only have two child views, of which only one is shown at a time.Or you can use `fragments`.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to if it is possible to have different layouts in the same activity, the answer is yes.

Activities are independent of layouts, you don't assign the layout for an activity in the manifest, you define what layout to use in the activity calling setContentView() method from Activity class to set a layout.

So if you want to have some layouts (screens) the only thing you have to do is define various layouts and use them when you want calling setContentView(R.layout.the layout), after this call, the layout chosen will be displayed.

If you can't create the layout statically by xml, you can create it dinamically by code as needed by demand each time you want.

In addition you can have a stack of layouts, each time you need a new screen, build it, push it to the stack and call setContentView() method, when you don't need it more, pop off the stack and call setContentView() with the new layout in the top of the stack.

Hope it help you